# iOS app rejected because of UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store-connect

I just got my app rejected for having a UIWebView. I launch a search and thus the user would be able to then search for anything, I suppose. My issue is I can't figure out how to set the rating in iTunes connect. The categories they have are for violence, gambling, etc, but my app doesn't fall into any of those categories by design. How does one set the rating in my case? 
I think I'm fine with living with a 17+ rating like Apple wants. I don't really want to launch safari and have users leave my app. How do I set it in iTunes connect? Any ideas?

Comment: app store review guidelines: 2.12 Apps that [...] are simply web sites bundled as Apps [...] may be rejected.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the "Add New App" wizard that you run through at itunes connect.  There is a section where you select radio buttons on questions for ratings.  Since the search could potentially include content from violence, gambling, etc just put those as Infrequent/Mild or Frequent/Intense.

Comment: that's true, but not answering the question how to CHANGE the rating.

Comment: You can't.  It's only available in the "Add New App" wizard.

Comment: If I put "Mature/Suggestive Themes" to frequent, it makes the app 17+. Even though my app doesn't contain any of that, is this the right thing to do? No "infrequent" setting will make it 17+.

Comment: I was under the impression that they specifically told you that your app was not approved due to an inappropriate rating.  If that's the case, and they didn't tell you what rating you needed to be approved, ask them. In Itunes Connect's Resolution Center, there is a text area where you can send some correspondance. Ask them what they're looking for and then set the ratings appropriately.

Comment: Yes. They rejected it and told me it should be 17+ because of possible unfiltered access to the internet. But they didn't tell me how exactly. I've sent them a message and they will likely tell me what to do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the rating when submitting a new version. So just create a new version and upload the same binary with new rating. Otherwise you could submit the app with 17+ rating and lower it to 4+ after review.